# rebranding rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, engineyard

I would like to rebrand my Rails app so that each user will have their own configuration like CSS, logos etc. We are storing the logos and fav icons in Amazon S3. Please let me know what is the best way to retrieve as if i retrieve from their for every request that will cost me lot of bandwidth because every page will have logo and the fav icon. I am looking for a most economic way of storing those images.

Answer (score 1):

You could download the logos running wget within RoR, telling the application to store it on a special folder.

But, the best way to save bandwidth would be directly linking the logos and favicons that are in Amazon S3.

Comment: linking will save the bandwidth anyways it need to render the image only from the site right ?

Comment: Right. you just need to link it in the view. Nothing will be sent or processed by your server.